# Best approach for android application automation

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Which would be a best approach to automate test cases for the android app. Suitable for continuous integration

Currently trying it out with Java + Appium + Docker. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This question is opinion-based and is not appropriate for the Stack Overflow format. More details on what makes a suitable question can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the Espresso as it is officially supported by google and best of the android UI testing.

With Espresso make it easy to write reliable user interface tests.

Simple demo for espresso :

```
@Test
fun checkTextDisplayed() {
onView(withId(R.id.txt_name)).perform(typeText("Steve"))
onView(withId(R.id.btn_click)).perform(click())
onView(withText("Hello Haresh!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```